# Apache Calcite Data Federation Usecase

Tags: apache-spark, apache-calcite

Just want to check if the Apache Calcite can be used for the use case "Data Federation"(query with multiple databases).

The idea is I have a master query (5 tables) that has  tables from one database (say Hive) and 3 tables from another database (say MySQL).

- Can I execute master query on multiple database from one JDBC Client interface ?
- If this is possible; where the query execution (particularly inter database join) happens?
- Also, can I get a physical plan from Calcite where I can execute explicitly in another execution engine?

I read from Calcite documentation that it can push down `Join` and `GroupBy` but I could not understand it? Can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Hi, Could you find any answer to the question? I have similar objective i.e. Data Federation.

Comment: Nope, I haven't found any answer.. I think the application has to implement all the functionalities through relational algebra provided by Calcite. My understanding is Calcite does not provide data federation (query decomposition) out of the box

Answer (score 4):

I will try to answer. you can as well send questions to the mailing list.   `dev@calcite.apache.org` you are more likely get answer there.

> Can I execute master query on multiple database from one JDBC Client interface ? If this is possible; where the query execution (particularly inter database join) happens?

yes, you can. the Inter database join happens in your memory where calcite runs.

> Can I get a physical plan from Calcite where I can execute explicitly in another execution engine?

yes, you can. a lot of calcite consumers are doing this way. but you will have to wrap around the calcite rule system, I mean `excute`

> I read from calcite documentation that it can push down Join and GroupBy but I could not understand it? Can anyone help me understand this?

these are the SQL optimisations that the engine does. imagine a groupBy which could have happened on a tiny table but actually specified after joining with a huge table.

Comment: Do you have any examples that show this? I am very much interested in this scenario (federated querying of two relational sources).